# Layout: directly D3 or with div/span in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have two D3 generated svgs on my HTML (at the moment both just in the body tag) and I would like to add a line of text below each of them. When I just add the text as D3 element it appears in line with the SVG on the right side but I want it below. I tried to add a div but that doesn't work either. So, do I have to play with the HTML or D3 layout?

This is the solution I have at the moment:
http://bl.ocks.org/sytpp/06e9cb3383b895e20c9a

(you have to open the vis in a new window http://bl.ocks.org/sytpp/raw/06e9cb3383b895e20c9a/)-I would like to have the text below the two bubble clouds directly below and not offset to the right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question has two parts:

- How do I position text below a chart?
- How do I position two charts next to each other?

To position text below a chart, wrap the chart div and the text div in a containing div. For example:

```
<div id='chart1-container'>
    <div id='chart1'></div>
    <div id='chart1-text'></div>
</div>
```

Then pass the id of the containing div into the `addChart` function:

```
function addChart(file, target, colScale, total, id) {
    var svg = d3.select(id).append("svg")
    // Remaining code
```

There are several ways to position two charts next to each other. However, I think the most straightforward is to position the containing divs absolutely, using CSS. I have added `width`, `height`, and `background-color` for illustration:

```
<head>

<style>

#chart1-container, #chart2-container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: steelblue;
}

#chart1-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

#chart2-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 420px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id='chart1-container'>
        <div id='chart1'></div>
        <div id='chart1-text'></div>
    </div>
    <div id='chart2-container'>
        <div id='chart2'></div>
        <div id='chart2-text'></div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Yes, that works (I updated the gist accordingly) but now I have everything in a new line: chart1, chart1-text, chart2, chart2-text. But I want to have the two charts side by side and the texts below respectively

Comment: This is more of an HTML/CSS question. I've updated my answer accordingly. It's not the only way to achieve your desired outcome, but I hope you find it simple enough to implement!

Answer (score 0):

In body tag add two div

```
<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

While calling the function call in this way

```
addChart("d2007.json", "container1", color_1, 223);
addChart("d2014.json", "container2", color_2, 659);
```

append svg in respective id as

```
var svg = d3.select("#"+target).append("svg")
        .attr("width", diameter)
        .attr("height", diameter)
        .attr("class", "bubble");
```

and text as

```
var svg2 = d3.select("#"+target).append("text")
        .text("# " + total)
        .attr("class", "text");
```

add this css in your style tag

```
.text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 150px;
}
#container1{
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}
#container2{
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I found a solution within D3:

I bound the svg with .append("g") and then added the text to the "g".

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter+140)
    .attr("class", "bubble")
    .append("g");

svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("y", 435)
    .style("font-size","40px")
    .text("Test Text");
```